# Autodesk Login - Authorize application screen with every login

Tags: oauth, autodesk-forge

We use the Autodesk OAuth [three-legged approach](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/) for authenticating with our application.

Today, every time that we log into our app, we are asked to authorize the application.

[image: Authorize App]

When we click Allow, most of the times we are authenticated, but sometimes this fails and we need to restart the browser.

Is this related to recent changes in the Forge platform's authentication?

Comment: I'm checking with the Authentication team...

Comment: Thank you Augusto. Let me know if you would like me to email more information on the context of this error.

Comment: As of Monday, May 1st, this is still an issue.

Comment: this is as designed, we're reviewing what else changed and will get back to you.

Comment: this happens every single time we authenticate.  if I close the browser and reopen it, I get challenged with the same "ALLOW/CANCEL" form during authentication, even though I just hit the "ALLOW" button a second ago.  this is new as of Friday, April 28th.  Prior to that, the service remembered that we had allowed our app access to these scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed now (as of May 2nd, 2017)

Comment: The problem has been fixed.  Thank you :-)

Comment: Augusto, this issue has resurfaced as of 9/26/2017.  We now got challenged to Authorize our Forge application every time we log in.  It seems the permissions are not sticking.

Comment: Hello, I'm not able to reproduce your authorization problem. Can you give me more details to check with our Authentication team. Have you tried cleaning up cache and on a different browser. I tried incognito mode already and the authorization is sticking.

Comment: It happens across browsers, users and machines for us.  We are using 3-legged authentication and are asked to authorize our application every time we log in. We require the following scopes:  { "bucket:read", "data:read", "data:create", "data:write", }